# Show that $f(x) \ne H(f)$ for all $f,x$.

Tags: functions

Given:
$$H = \lambda f \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow P(\mathbb{R}).\left\{ {x \in \mathbb{R}|x \notin f(x)} \right\}$$.

Show that $f(x) \ne H(f)$, for all $x, f$.

Well, this is my answer:
Let $y \in f(x)$.

By definition of $H$, $y \notin H(f)$.

Therefore, $H(f) \ne f(x)$.

is that good enough as a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. (1) At "let $y \in f(x)$", you also have to consider the case $f(x) = \emptyset$. (2) The statement $y \not \in H(f)$ does not follow from the definition of $H$: $H(f) = \{x \in {\mathbb R} \mid x \not\in f(x) \}$, so $y \not\in H(f)$ is equivalent to $y \in f(y)$.

You'd better split cases: $x \in f(x)$ or $x \not \in f(x)$.

Comment: What does it mean $x \in f(x)$? Maybe I get it wrong. Is it $x \in Im(f)$?

Comment: Well, it's your question :-) The $f$'s under consideration are functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\wp(\mathbb R)$. So $f(x)$ is a set of real numbers and $x$, being a real number, either belongs to it or not.

Comment: Of course, but for my understanding $f(x)=y$ where $y$ is a real number, and not a set. That said, how can you define $x \in f(x) = y \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Well, your $f$'s don't have ${\mathbb R}$ as codomain, but $\wp({\mathbb R})$. So $f(x)$ simply *is not* a real number. If it were, the statement "$x \in f(x)$" would be meaningless.